# iAd Network Says 0 requests, but MoPup says over 7k? 1% Fill Rate?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, iad, mopub

Like the title says... Mopub says I'm getting requests + impressions but apple doesn't?

Am I missing something in the mopub or iAd config?

Im including pictures for reference:

[image: mopub pic]

[image: iAd pic]

On a side note my fill rate is basically 0% and ads aren't showing up on my phone from the App Store but work perfectly fine in the testing environment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to make this work!

So to get admob working I had to lower the cpm in global segments to 0.01
(thats not what it really is but thats the configuration that finally started displaying ads.

What I had mistakenly done is lowered the cpm of iAD to 0.01 in the global segments section too thinking it would serve more ads...

All it did was break everything.

Put the cpm back 0.05 and now magically all my reporting and serving works

Hope this will help future people with issues using admob

(I'm using CocoonJS for everything too)